# Promotion with a EU Blue Card

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have received my EU Blue Card here in Germany in May of 2023, less than year after that I received a promotion from my employer: from Software Engineer to Senior Software Engineer.

Do I have to inform Ausländerbehörde about this or even receive permission from them?

Comment: Did you get a new job contract, or a formal notification to go with your old one? I presume the salary did not go *down* ...